# Shape Transparency in Python graphics module

Tags: python, object, transparency, shapes

So the thing is, I need to make a shape transparent in python using the graphics module and not the tkinter module. Is there any method for that. And if there is I'd like to know how it is used. Thanks

Comment: Your question needs more details about what you have tried so far,and some code. Also maybe  have a look at [this](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=-WULAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT356&lpg=PT356&dq=python+graphics+transparency&source=bl&ots=0v1FTRwOIj&sig=nci-07LEv5yzqfTIGX3SjuPtpFc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9h-rp_dXLAhUHKGMKHdikDN0Q6AEISDAH#v=onepage&q=python%20graphics%20transparency&f=false)

Comment: Thanks Tim Ogilvy. I've searched but what I mostly see is transparency in tkinter, and the link you suggested also talks about graphics in tkinter.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the graphics module? I can't work out which one you are referring to.

Comment: mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Answer (score 1):

If you are using John M Zelle's graphics library, it only supports rgb, not alpha (you can view the full source for graphics.py [here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py))

You will see the source contains no alpha capacity.

This post may help you:
[python tkinter canvas 'transparent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959914/python-tkinter-canvas-transparent)

Since graphics.py is just an OOP wrapper around tkinter anyway, you should be able to apply alpha in the same way, however I have not tested this.  You may be able to extend the graphics module simply to allow alpha.

Comment: Thanks. This has been helpful enough

Comment: Thanks. Given that I think I probably answered your question, even though I imagine it was not the answer you were hoping for, consider accepting my answer?